# Using little robots to speed up the stop motion animation process

Tags: animation, automation, stop-motion

I'm not very well experienced in the animations area,but I would like to be more and more experienced in the stop motion tecnique. I would like to know if someone uses pre built (or easy to build) little robots with the stop motion tecnique. I want to move their arms,the head,the legs with a remote control from my pc and then I will make a full video instead of capture single frames by moving their body parts with my hands. I hope that in this way the creation process will be faster. I don't know how could be the result,since I have no experience in the stop motion area,neither. But I wanna try. Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly the answer you are looking for, but absolutely worth the watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okCIHAbve3k

Comment: Stop motion animation (also called stop frame animation) is animation that is captured one frame at time, with physical objects that are moved between frames. When you play back the sequence of images rapidly, it creates the illusion of movement. - this site might be of help http://www.dragonframe.com/intro_to_stop_motion.php

Comment: I dont think you want stop motion then be reading the above question, with stop motion you are not just moving the "robot" but you are also moving the camera, back / fore ground elements to enhance the film. if you want to use a automated robot (or controllable) from a PC then animatronics might be the place to start. Stop animation takes time and a lot of it as there are so many elements to think about

Comment: what's is animatronic ? can you give me more informations about it ? a place to start ?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea sounds absolutely possible. On the other hand you write that you have never done any stop motion.

I think it would be very well advised to start with some basic techniques (by hand) and then see what you can maybe automate in the future.

Building puppets that can be easily animated is a already a complex task, since it usually involves building metal / wire skeletons etc. so I'd slowly approach the overall complexity of the matter and then advance to the next step.

Some introductory reading to get you started:

- Stop motion - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_motion
- Go motion https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_motion
- Pixilation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixilation
- Claymation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_animation
- Animatronics https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animatronics

I think what would more sense is to follow the idea mentioned by Adam Mann Pro using some basic animatronics.  If you build a remote controllable face for the puppets which allow you to easily setup facial expressions, that would speed up the animation process immensely and is in itself already very complex. Here is an example of an animatronics head from the movie "the world's end":